# How to increase headphone loudness beyond 100%?

Tags: audio, motorola-droid

I am very hard of hearing.

Is there a sound amplification app one can use with earbuds? Earbuds with a microphone for a Droid are a non-issue but I don't know where to find an inexpensive app to work with the hardware.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? But this application Volume+ might work for you if you're running Cyanogen Mod https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TEST.android.lvh&hl=en I'd read the instructions carefully though!

Comment: (Just sharing; and definitely not what you're looking for) I'm also hard of hearing, but I use a headset with my in-the-ear hearing aids.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one of the supported phone models:

There's an app called voodoo sound.

- [Voodoo Sound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.controlapp&hl=en) in Google's Play store
- Downside: Requires a *custom* kernel, only for supported phones (see description in market)

The paid app comes without a requirement for a custom kernel (but needs root)

- [Voodoo Sound Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.controlappdonate)

Both replace the audio codec's driver and allow fine tuning and to turn on formerly unused chip features (see description).